# sscanf returning -1 while scaning short int from a memory pointer in c?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to scan a `short int` (16 bits/2 bytes) from a memory pointer using `sscanf` as shown below. But it is showing some weird behaviour.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char p[] = {0x00, 0x1A};
    short int s = 0;
    int ret = sscanf(p,"%hu",&s);
    printf("Actual data %02x %02x\n",p[0],p[1]);
    printf("s = %hu ret = %d errno = %d\n",s,ret,errno);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Actual data 00 1a
s = 0 ret = -1 errno = 0
```

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong !

Comment: Note that it is [redundant and potentially dangerous to cast the result of malloc and friends in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/253056).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `p_extradata` is pointing at a `0x00` byte, so it looks like an empty string, hence there is nothing for `sscanf` to parse. Maybe you just want to *copy* those two bytes verbatim to your `short`, not convert a C string to a `short` ?

Comment: `sscanf()` with `%hu` and corresponding `(signed) short*` doesn't look good.

Comment: @EOF: true, but I don't think that's the main problem here.

Comment: @PaulR - why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @4386427: I would, but I am waiting for clarification from the OP as to what they actually want to achieve. They seem to have disappeared now though.

Comment: Edited the question so that results can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is pointing at a `0x00` byte, so it looks like an empty string, hence there is nothing for `sscanf` to parse.

It looks like just want to *copy* those two bytes *verbatim* to your `short`, not convert a C string to a `short` ? If so then instead of the `sscanf` call you could just use [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy):

```
memcpy(&s, p, sizeof(s));
```

Note that this assumes that your buffer and the destination `short` have the same endianness. If not then you will also need to take care of the byte order.

Comment: As I have edited the question the correct answer will be memcpy(&s, p, sizeof(s));

Comment: Updated - in future please don't radically alter the question once there are valid answers to the original question.

Comment: I was editing and the answers were already on their way, so once I saved I saw your answer. But then to revert will be not ok. So I kept it changed. BTW Thanks.

Comment: No problem - it was only a minor update anyway - just something to watch out for in future.

Comment: One more thing when I used "unsigned char p[] = {0x1B, 0x1A};" still the sscanf doesn't work. So that means sscanf does need a proper string terminated with \0 (NULL) to work with.

Comment: @SunnyShukla: `sscanf` is for parsing/converting *strings* into data - it looks like you just have *raw bytes*, so you just need to *copy* the data, not parse/convert it.